# OpenGL ES GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE

Tags: opengl-es

Does anyone know if GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE is supported in OpenGL ES? I am planning to use it for 2D graphics to support non-power-of-two images. My current implementation uses POT textures with alpha=0 padding is not doing well with stretched images. It is for OpenGL but we have plans of porting it to OpenGL ES as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There used to be
http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/texture_non_power_of_two.txt
which allows you to use non-power-of-two textures as a normal GL_TEXTURE_2D target.
No need to use GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE.

This has been incorporated into OpenGL 2.0:
See page 341 http://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/version2.0/glspec20.pdf

And I believe it also should just work in OpenGL ES:
See page 83 http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/es_full_spec_2.0.25.pdf

Comment: Thank you, I will do a little investigation and post back the results.

Comment: Thanks alot a gain, NPOT textures are working, now I have a reason to use OpenGL 2.0 :). and OpenGL ES does not specify *any* restrictions about image size. I guess this will imply that I can use it.