# iOS 5 undeclared identifier GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE

Tags: xcode, opengl-es, ios5, import, undeclared-identifier

I'm having trouble using a rectangular texture on iOS (iPhone 3gs or newer)

I'm trying to use `GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE` and/or `GL_EXT_texture_rectangle` but XCODE autocomplete doesn't recognize it, i think because the proper header file is not imported and throws me the `undeclared identifier` error.

Also tried `GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two` and `GL_ARB_texture_rectangle` as answered in this question [OpenGL ES GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883160/opengl-es-gl-texture-rectangle) but none are declared.

I've googled and haven't found a reference to the header it is declared, the header files used in the documentation sample projects are not found.

- Working on xcode 4.2

these are the headers I'm currently importing:

```
#import <OpenGLES/EAGL.h>
#import <OpenGLES/ES1/gl.h>
#import <OpenGLES/ES1/glext.h>
#import <OpenGLES/ES2/gl.h>
#import <OpenGLES/ES2/glext.h>
```

also tried to import these

```
#import <OpenGL/OpenGL.h> //file not found
#import <OpenGL.h> //file not found
#import <OpenGL/glu.h> //file not found
```

Comment: Thanks for the support. After all I decided not to use rectangle textures but instead to create a new power of two texture from the rectangular image dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL ES on iOS doesn't support rectangle textures. [See here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/OpenGLESPlatforms/OpenGLESPlatforms.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH106-SW1) for full list of OpenGL ES extensions supported on iOS.

Are you using ES 1.1 or ES 2.0? ES2 has NPOT texture support, so you could use that instead of rectangle textures.

Comment: Hi thanks, Actually I'm using es 2.0 but should be using 1.1 as well, logic defines when each version is used. I Tried using `GL_APPLE_texture_2D_limited_npot` everywhere instead of `GL_TEXTURE_2D` but the textures blaked out.

Comment: Make sure you comply to the restrictions listed for this extension: http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/APPLE/APPLE_texture_2D_limited_npot.txt Meaning "... both the texture wrap mode is CLAMP_TO_EDGE and the minification filter is NEAREST or LINEAR".